# Options for paying for a nonreturnable leased vehicle

Tags: loans, repayment, bankruptcy

Late last year, my girlfriend's car was stolen and subsequently destroyed. This car was a leased vehicle. For reasons beyond her control<sup>‡</sup>, the insurance had lapsed a few months prior. The vehicle is due to be returned next month, and the finance team says she needs to pay the remaining balance of the car if it is not returned, approximately 14K USD. She is not able to obtain a loan at her credit union.

What are her options for repaying the car? If she cannot pay, what then? Is this a situation where bankruptcy might be considered (she does not have the means to repay this without getting a loan)?

Note: I believe her mother is a co-signer on this lease, so preventing as much blow-back to her as possible would be best.

---

‡: *The insurance was being paid by an aunt who failed to inform my girlfriend that she was transferring responsibility of paying to my girlfriend. As far as my girlfriend knew, the car was insured.*

Comment: Why was the insurance lapsing "beyond her control"?

Comment: It was being paid by an aunt who failed to inform my girlfriend that the aunt was transferring responsibility of paying to my girlfriend (too many feminine pronouns...). As far as she knew, it was insured.

Comment: You've got two good answers, worth adding that there was a $14k theft/casualty loss that can be deducted on someone's return (hopefully the mother's). Not ideal, but the tax savings will help.

Comment: I feel like the mother should go after her sister for restitution--not in court, I mean, but within the family. How can anyone just stop paying insurance that a family member is relying on without telling them?

Comment: What about involving the said aunt into the deal?

Comment: Because your gf didn't own the car, isn't the theft from the lease provider? I think you should go to a real good lawyer real quick instead of spending time on stackexchange. I assume a lot depends on your jurisdiction. Also something to consider is wasn't lease provider responsible to inform your gf about lack of insurance?

Comment: I hate to be a bringer of additional bad news, but although not directly relevant to the question asked, I suspect your GF and her Mom are going to be in trouble with the leasing agency over the lapsed insurance as well.  I can't imagine maintaining coverage not being a requirement of the lease itself.

Comment: As a note of resolution, she was able to talk with the lender and secure a payment plan (i.e. just continuing payments past the return date). They will re-evaluate the situation in 120 days, every 120 days, possibly writing off some of the amount. Now why they couldn't tell her this the first 5 times she called them, I don't know...

Comment: I'm scratching my head wondering why the actual owner isn't liable for outright theft. Yeah sure if girlfriend crashed it she's liable but it was stolen and that's a completely different beast.

Comment: @Joshua I assume because the terms of the lease state a requirement of insurance because the lender doesn't want to pay to carry it's own. Not to mention, by law, you as a person are required to carry some, if not trivial, amount of insurance. If the car was destroyed in a collision, it would be the same thing, since usually the insurance picks up the tab and pays the lender.

Comment: @Drise Glad to know that working things out with the lender was possible.  That's nearly always the best option in situations like this, and definitely a good outcome here, assuming she can continue making said payments anyway.

Comment: @Joshua Exactly as Drise says.  The terms of the loan require the lessee to carry insurance, and not carrying said insurance would be in breach of that contract.  It's possible that if they were to go to court that they'd end up less than fully liable (depending on the complete terms of the lease); but the lessor would certainly have a good case at least.  Of course, this ambiguity is one incentive the lessor had to negotiate a payment plan and/or write off part of the loan...

Comment: @Joe Since this incident, I've been keeping a better eye on both our finances, so this doesn't happen again. We've fixed a lot of the issues the got us to this point, but unfortunately that doesn't help the initial issue.

Comment: The insurance you are required to carry by law is liability insurance.

Comment: @Joshua one would hope that the lease contract requires the person taking out the lease to take responsibility for the property.

Comment: @Joshua By law, yes. But by traty, you might have more liabilities.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73220/discussion-on-question-by-drise-options-for-paying-for-a-nonreturnable-leased-ve).

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. I don't see how the leasing bank could allow this to happen. I thought the insurance company is required to notify the bank if the policy is canceled unless proof of new insurance is provided. Upon hearing the news the bank either repos the car or purchases the insurance and bills you for it. So the way I see it, either the insurance company screwed up and didn't contact the bank, or the bank was contacted and forgot to purchase the insurance, or the car actually *was* insured and they weren't admitting it. A good attorney could have wiggled you out of this.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Unfortunately this is going to land in her mother's lap. Since she is a cosigner on the lease she is just as responsible as your girlfriend for paying the return value. *Both* of them would have to declare bankruptcy to get the debt discharged.

If I were in her situation, and I could not get a loan for the remainder, I would work out a deal with my mother to pay off the lease and pay her back as quickly as possible. I would also get everything in writing to protect both of us - how much is owed, when the payments will be, consequences for late payments, etc. Just as if I were borrowing it from a bank.

You could *try* working something out with the financer, but with a cosigner that is presumably *able* to pay, I would be shocked if they settled for anything less than the full amount.

I know the last thing your girlfriend wants right now is a lecture, but this deal has four bad components that hopefully will be a learning experience:

- Don't lease vehicles. There are cases where leasing *might* make sense, but it is the most expensive way to finance a car, and is usually used to get more car that you can afford.
- Don't let your insurance lapse. The *point* of insurance is to protect against catastrophic losses like this.
- Don't get someone to co-sign a loan. It is a sign that you're borrowing money for something that you can't afford, and puts tremendous risk (and probably stress) on both parties
- Don't put someone else in charge of paying your bills. If your girlfriend had been in control of the insurance up front, this whole thing might have been avoided. The fact that someone else is paying the insurance is another sign that she couldn't afford the car.

Again, I feel sorry for her being in this situation, but at this point the only good advice I can give is to help her avoid the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: Yeah a leased vehicle with a co-signer just absolutely screams you can't afford this and shouldn't be doing this. Unfortunately, my father ended up doing a similar thing for someone he was trying to help out and my parents now have a leased car they didn't want. I'm sure the person he was trying to help out would have been much better off with a descent used car too. It would have cost them much less over the time they used it.

Comment: “Don't lease vehicles. There are cases where leasing might make sense, but it is the most expensive way to finance a car“ actually, if you have a company and can deduct the lease from taxes, this isn't true.

Comment: @DonQuiKong , business lease is a completely different financial beast to personal Leasing (well it is in the UK)

Comment: It is simply not true that leasing is a universally bad way to finance a car. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: @DonQuiKong 1) We're not talking about a business, and 2) you can also deduct the depreciation when you buy a car versus lease it (in the US at least, and I suspect many other countries).

Comment: @JackAidley I admitted there might be scenarios where it makes sense, but those are probably for a _business_. I can't think of a valid reason for an individual to lease (rent) a car for three years and have nothing to show for it at the end.

Comment: @DStanley Wait, what? An individual can deduct depreciation on their personal vehicle?  Have I been missing out on thousands of dollars in tax savings over the last 30 years?

Comment: @Michael No, a _business_ can deduct depreciation or a lease payment as an expense. A individual that uses a car for business cannot deduct depreciation but can deduct either a lease payment (proportional to your business usage) or mileage, but not both.

Comment: It is not true that getting a co-signer on a loan is a sign that you're borrowing money for something that you can't afford.  A co-signer is often required for people with no credit history regardless of income. Further using a cosigner will often allow the borrower to get a much better interest rate than they would on their own.  (Because the co-signer's credit is factored in.)

Comment: Your girlfriend and/or her aunt also ignored at least one written notice of cancellation of insurance. Perhaps a phone call or email from agents, too. This is an entire family with serious issues about money and paying attention, including willingness to buy more car than they can really afford. Your girlfriend is presumably young and might learn better. But keep your eyes open that _your_ money doesn't get sucked into this family's drama.

Comment: @JustinOhms In other words you cosign a loan when you believe the borrower is much more credit-worthy than the bank believes. Just hang around Stack Exchange and you'll see how often the bank turns out to be right.

Comment: @user20574 : Not "much more credit-worthy" - just "more credit-worthy". I've acted as a guarantor for my son's rent when he was a student.  (I was right about my son's reliability.)  I would certainly consider acting as a guarantor for my son's mortgage.

Comment: @user20574  The first part of your statement is true. Of course I know more about the finances, character and likelihood to repay of a borrower that I know personally than a bank that is working off of a sparse or non-existent credit report.  The second part of your statement is not statistically provable as it inherits a large natural selection bias since people who co-sign on loans that are paid off by the primary borrower with no incident or default are unlikely to give it even a second thought much less post about it on the internet.

Comment: @MartinBonner So how credit-worthy is your son in your belief compared to the bank's belief?

Answer (score 23):

If there is a cosigner, then bankruptcy on the part of your girlfriend won't be helpful: the mother will simply be fully responsible.

The first option here should be to talk to the dealership/lessor.  It's entirely possible they will be willing to work with your girlfriend in order to avoid a default.  Lenders don't want defaults, they don't want to sell off your account for $0.20 on the dollar or anything of that nature.  So they're often willing to make a deal - either reducing the total amount owed, or allowing payments over time.  But be up front about everything immediately.  Be prepared to prove it was stolen (police report, etc.); and understand that the lack of insurance probably voids the lease.  That's a sunk cost though; don't try to hide any of it, just be honest and forthright and ask nicely.

Second, your girlfriend could try to obtain a personal loan (unsecured) to pay for the difference.  I don't know her credit, but if it's decent it's possible to get several thousand dollars at a non-usurious rate (10-15%).  It's at least worth a shot.  If her credit is in the "gets random credit card offers in the mail that don't have annual fees" range, she probably qualifies for something like this.  But if she's going into a lease with a cosigner, perhaps she doesn't have any/good credit - but perhaps a few years later she does now?

Third, your girlfriend should talk to her mother.  She should do this *anyway*; the first option will possibly have a negative impact on her credit as well. It's critical to make sure she's open with her mother as well: hiding this won't be possible, and not telling her about it and letting her find out from her credit report is a big mistake.

But if the first two options don't pan out, she would have to involve her mother in some way; assuming the mother can either pay it off or get a loan herself, anyway.  A reasonable solution here might be for the mother to get the personal loan and have your girlfriend pay that personal loan, though I recommend in that case that she pay her mother rather than pay the lender (so her mother can pay the lender and ensure no missed payments).

Finally: don't get another car lease, unless and until you two are financially comfortable and independent.  This was a mistake *going in*; buying something that requires you to have a cosigner means you're buying something over your means.

Comment: I disagree with your last statement. When I was purchasing my first car, I was required a cosigner, not because I couldn't afford it, but from my distinct lack of credit history. Yes, it usually means, the purchase is above your means, but not always.

Comment: Finally: Always pay all your cars in cash! Leasing is a financing model with certain advantages for companies which don´t apply to private persons

Comment: @Daniel I disagree with the idea of paying in cash.  There's certainly risk involved in financing, but strictly speaking, if you can get a low interest loan with low payments and have the discipline to invest the cash you would have spent, it is financially better to keep as much of your cash invested as possible. The key is the interest rate on the loan vs the expected return on the investment.   Even with young people who CAN'T get a good rate, creating a credit history has its own value that cannot be discounted.

Comment: I have to disagree here - it is not about interst vs return on investment. A new car **looses value** so fast that that they will make any interst/investment calculations irrelevant. What you wrote applies for a house, maybe a collectors car etc. - Buying a car is spending money you will never see again. You should not spend money you do not have!

Comment: @rcollyer You were required to get a cosigner because *you took out a loan for a car*.  At 18, which is the only point in which someone should have no credit history, *taking out a loan for a car* is getting more car than you can on your own get.  It's entirely reasonable to buy an inexpensive car with cash at 18, in my opinion, if there's not a family hand-me-down car available

Comment: @Daniel My understanding is that the point is not to treat the car as an investment but to invest the money that would otherwise have been used to buy the car in something with a higher rate of return than the car loan. Certainly riskier than buying the car in full but not really an issue if you could have afforded the car anyway.

Comment: @JAB it is an issue if the car is destroyed with no insurance, and the value of your investment has _dropped_ - then you're worse off. That's the point, that investments returns are not guaranteed but loan payments are.

Comment: @DStanley And if you pay for the car in cash and don't get insurance and the car is destroyed then you're still out the money and don't have the possibility of an investment making it up. You should have insurance in either situation anyway, particularly as in many places you can be held liable for damages caused by your car if you don't.

Comment: I don't know that car loans are low enough interest that they justify being treated as identical to mortgages here.  I buy the "mortgage payment has 3.5% return, investment return is higher" argument.  I think a car loan is more like 6%, and if you're not paying 6% you probably paid a higher price on the car than you needed to.  Ultimately, 6% is about what it should be all things considered, and that is no longer significantly lower than a mildly risk-averse market return.

Comment: @JAB: If you think it is a good idea to invest lent money, you don´t need to buy a car for this. Does not change the fact that a car is essentially a consumable - you would not pay for an expensive meal with a loan, while investing the money elsewhere, would you? A house on the other hand is just a less liquid form of capital, and therfore a completley different case!

Comment: @Daniel The number of people who hand over a credit card at the dinner table while simultaneously investing money is probably fairly large...  but either way this should move to chat and/or a separate question as it's irrelevant to this answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Would you agree that a good rule is "Never buy a car unless you're able to pay cash."  The choice to take the secured loan or not can be separated from the choice of car, but any car you don't have the cash for is too much car.

Comment: @Joe there is a disconnect here. I was required a cosigner because the bank did not have enough info in my prior history to determine if I'd be reliable in making the payments. There is a difference between being able to afford the payment and the bank believing you can reliably do so. The same thing would be true if I had been in a divorce and my wife had trashed my credit score. While they _usually_ coincide, they don't always.

Comment: @rcollyer No disconnect, I fully understand what you're saying.  But that doesn't mean you had to buy a car that required a loan at all.

Answer (score 12):

How about suing the car thieves for restitution?  Civil cases can stick even where criminal ones do not.  This is a direct result of the car being stolen.  Make them pay, literally!

Comment: You're assuming that A) the identity of the thieves is known, and that B) they have the ability to pay even in theory.   The latter is unlikely even if the former is known; people with money generally don't steal cars; and someone getting 30 cents/day stamping license plates in a prison factory won't be able to pay anything meaningful.

Comment: The police never discovered who did it. They found the car torched in a parking lot.

Answer (score 4):

Your girlfriend needs to consult a lawyer.

Driving car with no insurance is against (almost?) every state's laws. Admitting that she did so to third parties (the dealer/lender) may not be wise.

The lease contract almost certainly specifies that the vehicle must be fully insured. Failing to live up to her end of the contract may have consequences.

She needs to consult an attorney for advice before she talks to anyone else about this. An consultation doesn't have to cost a lot of money, and might even be free, but whatever money it does cost is going to be worth it.

Comment: I don't believe you can have action taken against you for something you did in the past (non-criminal at least). As far as I know, this is a citation level offense, being that you get fined if you get pulled over and can't produce proof of insurance. I don't see how admitting to this after the fact (and now having fixed the lack of insurance issue) could present (state legal) problems, just as if you admit you were speeding or missed a stop sign at some point in the past.

Comment: Honestly, I don't believe so, either, but OP's GF needs to talk to a lawyer anyways, so might as well ask about that at the same time.

Comment: the best advice here.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to negotiate the value of the car down. Based on age and mileage, but beyond that, she is going to have to pay off the car.